# Aligning equation numbers inside and outside of an algorithm

Tags: vertical-alignment, algorithm2e

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{my capt}
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\algomargin\relax}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item step 1
        \item step 2
        \item step 3 
        \begin{equation}\label{alg1}
            \tau = x + y.
        \end{equation}
        \item step 5
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
\end{algorithm}
I have an equation:
\begin{equation}\label{myeq}
        \alpha = x^2 y.
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Here in the above MWE, I use a minipage environment to avoid getting an overfull hbox error. I want to align the equation numbers vertically inside and outside the algorithm. It looks like in the figure below. I want to align equations (1) and (2):

[image: It looks like this. I want to align equation numbers (1) and (2).]

How can I do that?

This question is very similar to the one posted here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460466/139314
Instead of a box, I have an algorithm environment.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want it perfectly aligned, repeat both the minipage and use `\item[]` (itemize instead of enumerate).

Comment: I either couldn't get it, or it didn't work. I added one more minipage and used itemize, and it pushed the equation number (1) more inside.

Comment: When I do that I get an overfull hbox error (that's why I used minipage), and the line is too wide. Also, I want to have it with enumerate if possible. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Interestingly, algorithm does shift everything to the right by \algomargin, but it does not change \@totalleftmargin, \leftskip, or \linewidth.  It does change \hsize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This aligns the inner equation to the outer equation (as opposed to aligning the outer to the inner).  It uses `\makebox` to overlap the left margin, and negative `\hspace` to overlap the right margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{my capt}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item step 1
        \item step 2
        \item step 3\\
        \makebox[\dimexpr \linewidth-2\algomargin][r]{% overlap left margin
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}% equation is in vmode
        \begin{equation}\label{alg1}
            \tau = x + y.
        \end{equation}
        \end{minipage}\hspace{-\algomargin}}% overlap right margin
        \item step 5
    \end{enumerate}
\end{algorithm}
I have an equation:

\begin{equation}\label{myeq}
        \alpha = x^2 y.
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That looks great, but I get the error: `Overfull \hbox (17.62482pt too wide) detected`. What can be wrong?

Comment: Not sure, but I didn't get overfull error with `\textwidth-\algomargin`.  The new version uses `\textwidth-2\algomargin`

Comment: I think linebreak `\\` causes this error. I keep getting it, although I tried the new version.

Comment: Does `\newline` or `\par` work better?

Comment: No, none of them has worked. But, I have found a workaround using your method: instead of using `enumerate`, I used `linesnumbered` option. For the line with an equation it was adding a line number and I disable it using this trick: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153646/algorithm2e-disabling-line-numbers-for-specific-lines

Works perfectly now! Thank you so much, again!